# Calling the main function inside a callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, flatten

I am struggling to understand the following code:

```
let myArray = ["J", "a", "v", ["a", "scrip"], "t"];

const flatten = (myArray) => {
  return myArray.reduce((flat, arry) => {
    return Array.isArray(arry) ? flat.concat(flatten(arry)) : flat.concat(arry);
  }, []).join("");
};
console.log(flatten(myArray));
// Output => Javascript
```

I'm confused about why the `flatten` "Main function" is called inside the `reduce` function with the `arry` parameter. Since the `reduce` function goes through the `myArray`, why is it necessary? When I tried removing the `flatten` call inside the `reduce` callback function, as in the following:

```
const flatten = (myArray) => {
  return myArray.reduce((flat, arry) => {
    return Array.isArray(arry) ? flat.concat(arry) : flat.concat(arry);
  }, []).join("");
};
console.log(flatten(myArray))
```

the code produced the same outcome. So, why is the main function call needed, and how does it make a difference? I just need to understand how things really work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, try with `["J", "a", "v", ["a", "s", ["cr", "ip"]], "t"]` - by the way, `return Array.isArray(arry) ? flat.concat(arry) : flat.concat(arry);` would just be `return flat.concat(arry);` would it not?

Comment: Consider what `arry` actually is, then what `Array.isArray(arry)` is testing for, then create some test data with a mix of `arry` values that are and are not arrays, then try that test data without the recursive call.

Comment: by the way, modern JS ... `myArray.flat(Infinity).join('')` does what that code does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion).

If you do the first version, it doesn't matter how deep the array goes, it always returns `Javascript`, but if you take out the recursion, then you end up with something else.

With recursion

```js
let myArray = ["J", ["a", "v"], ["a", "s", ["c", ["r", "i"], "p"]], "t"];

const flatten = (myArray) => {
  return myArray.reduce((flat, arry) => {
    return Array.isArray(arry) ? flat.concat(flatten(arry)) : flat.concat(arry);
  }, []).join("");
};

console.log(flatten(myArray))
```

Without recursion

```js
let myArray = ["J", ["a", "v"], ["a", "s", ["c", ["r", "i"], "p"]], "t"];

const flatten = (myArray) => {
  return myArray.reduce((flat, arry) => {
    return Array.isArray(arry) ? flat.concat(arry) : flat.concat(arry);
  }, []).join("");
};

console.log(flatten(myArray))
```

You can run the code snippets to see, how they return different results.

Answer (score 1):

That is called recursion. The idea is that you iterate through the array, if another array is found, then call the same function again the that array. Otherwise, just concat the value to the result.

Use the following array and run the code with and without calling `flatten` recursively, you'll see the difference.

`let myArray = ["J", "a", "v", ["a", "scrip"], "t", [' ','is', [' ', 'awe', ['some']]]];`